# Request and response types in WCF

Tags: wcf, request, response

I see a huge number of request and response types in a project to cater for all the endpoints exposed as WCF services. This seems like an awful lot of repetitive, simple code to maintain.

Can these types be auto-generated or avoided altogether using something like attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be autogenerated a few ways.  The two I'm most familiar with:

[Web Service Software Factory - Modeling Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648382.aspx).  You maintain a UML-like model and let the factory generate much of your code.  Code is generated as partial classes so you can manually add/override methods and more complex schema.

I also sometimes define all of the data in XML Schema, then use [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) to generate the contracts from the schema.  Again, it creates partial classes so that you can tweak the generated contracts.